# Using Linq to merge all List returned by the method of an object in a List

Tags: c#, linq

So this is my test case :

I have a class QuizzResult that hold all the answer choosen by a user:

```
public class QuizzResult
{
    public List<int> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

When the test is finished, I have a list of results:

```
List<QuizzResult> allResult
```

So I just want to have the list (with duplicates) of all the merged answers of all QuizzResults.

I tried to look around Select, but I have a IEnumerable>. I fell I should use ForEach, but I don't know how...

Any hint?

Comment: Do you just want `allResult.SelectMany(x => x.Answers)`;

Comment: I've added this as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SelectMany` will flatten your list of lists into one single enumerable of answers:

```
IEnumerable<int> allAnswers = allResult.SelectMany(quizz => quizz.Answers);
```

To get `List<int>` use `ToList` extension method, which will eagerly read all the items and create a `List`

```
List<int> allAnswers = allResult.SelectMany(quizz => quizz.Answers)
                                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

As my comment was the required answer, converting to an answer.

When you wish to combine a collection of collections into a single collection you can use the 
`SelectMany` [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
allResult.SelectMany(x => x.Answers)
```

This will use defered execution so if you wish to evaluate this immediately, tag a `ToList` or `ToArray` call on the end.  As you are using Lists, here is an example with `ToList`

```
 List<int> allAnswers = allResult.SelectMany(x => x.Answers).ToList();
```